# Laravel Email, send multiples e-mails

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I'm trying to send a mail to multiples providers

`$email['success']` is equals to:

```
0 => {
  'name' => 'Quimer Comercial Ltda.',
  'email' => 'anapaula.vendas@quimer.com.br'
},
1 => {
  'name' => 'Doce Aroma Industria e Comercio - 47'
  'email' => 'docearoma@docearoma.com.br'
},
2 => {
  'name' => 'Purifarma Distr.quimica e Farmac. Ltda.'
  'email' => 'purifarma@purifarma.com.br'
}
```

That is my code:

```
$mail = new NewCotacao($codigoempresa, $codigocotacao);
foreach($emails['success'] as $email){
    Mail::to($email['email'])->send($mail);
}
```

But look what is happening

[image]

I want to looks like this to each one

```
To: anapaula.vendas@quimer.com.br
```

---

```
To: docearoma@docearoma.com.br
```

---

```
To: purifarma@purifarma.com.br
```

Comment: It would be better if you suppress personal information in your question.

Comment: @Laerte I was just putting my tries, but I'll remove then

Comment: You should send your emails through a queue. [Queueing Mail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#queueing-mail)

Comment: @RamyHerrira thank you, I'll study it

Comment: I am not familiar with the Laravel Mail class but it looks like you need to emtpy the `to` field between the calls.

Comment: @jeroen I tried that, but it looks awkward `From: blah@blah.blah` `To: `

Comment: It might help to move my ip to black list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create separate `Mailable` to each user:

```
foreach($emails['success'] as $email){
    $mail = new NewCotacao($codigoempresa, $codigocotacao);
    Mail::to($email['email'])->send($mail);
}
```

If you are using same `Mailable` instance, the recipients will get appended.

```
// Extracted from vendor source code
// File: illuminate/mail/Mailable.php

/**
 * Set the recipients of the message.
 *
 * @param  object|array|string  $address
 * @param  string|null  $name
 * @return $this
 */
public function to($address, $name = null)
{
    return $this->setAddress($address, $name, 'to');
}

/**
 * Set the recipients of the message.
 *
 * All recipients are stored internally as [['name' => ?, 'address' => ?]]
 *
 * @param  object|array|string  $address
 * @param  string|null  $name
 * @param  string  $property
 * @return $this
 */
protected function setAddress($address, $name = null, $property = 'to')
{
    foreach ($this->addressesToArray($address, $name) as $recipient) {
        $recipient = $this->normalizeRecipient($recipient);
        $this->{$property}[] = [
            'name' => $recipient->name ?? null,
            'address' => $recipient->email,
        ];
    }
    return $this;
}
```